# ImageView not displaying inside of HorizontalScrollView in android

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have an image that is 8000 pixels long that I would like to scroll through horizontally. When I insert the image as an ImageView into a HorizontalScrollView and run it on a physical device (Samsung galaxy nexus), the scrollbar suggests that the image was loaded, but no image is displayed. Everything displays correctly in the android xml viewer.
Here is my xml for the horizontalScrollView:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TableRow01"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/longimage" />
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have tried wrapping the image in several other layouts and on its own, but nothing has worked on the device. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with some small Image, are you sure you are not getting any crash logs ?

Comment: Ah thanks! There is a crash log: Bitmap too large to be uploaded as a texture. How would I upload the image then?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the params of the imageView to match_parent.